# How to create a nav bar that is absolute and relative footer with an absolute body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this so far however how do I ensure I have an absolute body with a relative footer.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">

     </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "always at the bottom" and "not fixed" Those two requirements are conflicting in my head. If it is always at the bottom, then surely it is fixed? Bottom of what? The webpage or the screen? It the user scrolls, do you expect it to move?

Comment: I've edited the question..I wont see the nav bar until I scroll to the very bottom of the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it with **absolute** and **relative** positions:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 999px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
```

The **'body'** is your container and the **'footer'** is your nav-bar.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeevkatz/k4jshq8r/)

Comment: Needs to be there all the time